# "Reactjs" How to create a modal inside a functional component without using hooks

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

Can we create a toggle-able modal in a functional component without using hooks. Actually I'm trying to design a modal in a functional component but I couldn't achieve what I tried for. And on google, all I could find is hooks.
here's what I wrote but its not working

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, Button, Modal, ModalHeader } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

let isModalOpen = false;

const toggleModal = () => {
   isModalOpen = !isModalOpen;
   console.log(isModalOpen);
}

function RenderComments({comments}) {
if(comments!=null){
    const list = comments.map((comment) =>{
        let options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        let dt = new Date(comment.date);
        return (
            <li key={comment.id}>
                {comment.comment}<br/><br/>
                -- {comment.author}, {dt.toLocaleString('en-US', options)}
                <br/><br/>
            </li>  
        );
    });
    return(
        <div className="col-12 col-md-7 mt-3 mb-3">
            <h4>Comments</h4>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                {list}
            </ul>
            <Button onClick={toggleModal} outline color="secondary"><span className="fa fa-pencil"></span> Submit Comment</Button>
        </div>
    );
}else{
    return (<div></div>);
}  
}

const DishDetail = (props) => {
if(props.dish!=undefined){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <Breadcrumb>
                    <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                    <BreadcrumbItem active>{props.dish.name}</BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>{props.dish.name}</h3>
                </div>
                <RenderDish dish = {props.dish} />
                <RenderComments comments = {props.comments} />
            </div>
            <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} toggle={toggleModal}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggleModal}>
                    Login
                </ModalHeader>
            </Modal>
         </div>
    )
}else{
    return(<div></div>);
}
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Can somebody please explain why this piece of code is not working?

in debugger I found that isOpen attribute of modal is always false and is not changing on clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works but the react component is not rerendered because react doesn't know something has changed, that's why you have to use an useState hook.

that doesn't change the code much, just put the isModalOpen state at the top of the function

```
const [isModalOpen, setisModalOpen] = useState(false);

const toggleModal = () => {
   setisModalOpen(!isModalOpen);
   console.log(isModalOpen);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the help but I am doing a course which this assignment is a part of. And its an old course which doesn't have the hooks. So I am wondering if there's a way to achieve the required functionality without using hooks.

Comment: well you could add the isModalOpen as a prop of your component and change it from the parent